# Pairiwse jaccard similarity using minhash algorithm

Tags: performance, text, similarity, minhash

I am working with 200k sentences and I want to find Jaccard similarity using minhash algorithm. but it becomes really slow because of two for loops. could someone suggest me some good implementation?

Below is my current code

```
from datasketch.minhash import MinHash

def eg1(data1, data2):
    m1 = MinHash()
    m2 = MinHash(enter code here)
    for d in data1:
        m1.update(d.encode('utf8'))
    for d in data2:
        m2.update(d.encode('utf8'))
    return m1.jaccard(m2)

jac_sim = []
for i_doc in range(len(shingles)-1):
    for j_doc in range(i_doc + 1, len(shingles)):
        jaccard_similarity = eg1(shingles[i_doc], shingles[j_doc])
        jac_sim.append(jaccard_similarity)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that MinHash is calculated many times for the same input. By calculating MinHash signatures only once you should by able to save a lot of time:

```
signatures = []
for i_doc in range(len(shingles)):
    m = MinHash()
    for d in shingles[i_doc]:
        m.update(d.encode('utf8'))
    signatures.append(m)

jac_sim = []    
for i_doc in range(len(shingles)-1):
    for j_doc in range(i_doc + 1, len(shingles)):
        jaccard_similarity = signatures[i_doc].jaccard(signatures[j_doc])
        jac_sim.append(jaccard_similarity)
```